# How to find the left and right side limits of $f(x)=|1+x|√−1x,f:R→R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I need to find the left and right side limit of the function stated below, but I'm having a hard time simplifying the equation. The question is:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{|1+x|}-1}{x} &\text{if}\, x \ne 0\\ 0 &\text{if}\, x = 0\end{cases}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{(|1+x|)}-1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{-\sqrt{(1+x)}-1}{x}$$

But where do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that $$\frac{\sqrt{|x+1|}-1}{x}=\frac{|x+1|-1}{x(\sqrt{|x+1|}+1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $ |1+x|>0 $, no matter whether $ x \rightarrow 0+ $ or  $ x \rightarrow 0- $, the correct limit value would be

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{(|1+x|)}-1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{(1+x)}-1}{x}$

or

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{(|1+x|)}-1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{(1+x)}-1}{x}$  .

So, Right hand limit and left hand limit are the same. Next, proceed by rationalising the numerator and find the limit